# AJAX search in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, search

My aim is to 'ajaxify' WordPress search. So far I have written an AJAX call which passes the user submitted query string to my PHP handler. The parts I'm struggling with are:

1 The PHP handler.

WordPress already has its own PHP search script which I'd like to make use of. How should I integrate this into my PHP handler? Is there an easy way or will I need to rewrite the search script myself?

2 The AJAX response

How should I pass the search results from my PHP handler back to my script? Would I just pass the whole HTML as a string? something like `echo json_encode( $html );`

I realize my questions are fairly broad so no need for exact code examples. I'm more in need of some high-level ideas as to the approach I should take.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If data transfer is a concern, I recommend sending the data back as a JSON object, rather than full HTML.  You'll save bytes and bytes.

Do you have access to the built-in PHP search script function?  You could tear open the file and copy/paste their code into your own function.

Just thinking from a broad AJAX/PHP perspective (coming from working with vBulletin a lot, and never having worked with WordPress).

Comment: Thanks for the edit! i should have spotted the possessive pronoun! And thanks for your comments I'll look into the JSON object approach

Comment: Once you get the data back, it's fairly simple to loop through the JSON object array and create HTML with javascript/jQuery.  It's client side heavy that way, so, whichever side you're trying to limit the processing on (transfer vs. client CPU/browser), is which side you should err on.

Comment: Great tip regarding where the processing is done, I'll definitely look into that to take some weight off the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress' search handler is not actually a handler at all. It's part of the `WP_Query` class. Technically there are some special methods that parse the search string and return relevant results, but you don't have to do anything with those. To use Wordpress to search posts simply add the `s` argument to the query, like so:

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   's' => 'foobar'
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);

 return json_encode($query);
```

Make sure you write your AJAX in a [protected function](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) so that people cant submit their own queries on your database. Wordpress will prevent SQL injection, but it's still better safe than sorry.

```
function SearchConstructor(value){
    function myAjaxCall(){
        $.ajax({
            // Your AJAX Call
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            return msg;
        });
    }

    this.get = function(){
        return myAjaxCall.call(this);
    }
};
```

Here is [a better blog post](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-inject-protected-methods-in.html) on protecting functions.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the search handler. In that case, couldn't I just do something like `global $wp_query; return json_encode( $wp_query );` in my PHP handler?

Comment: Regarding the protected function - I never thought of people trying to submit their own db queries! Any chance you could give a quick example of how to write one?

Comment: You could use the global query, definitely. That may give you weird results, but you can try it! As for the protected function, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I was thinking if `s` is set then the global query will be the same as the search query? And `s` will always be set if the code in my PHP handler is running...

Comment: Ah, not in this instance. You are instantiating a new query. You shouldn't actually affect the global query object as long as you AJAX handler is not setting anything to the global query object (which you would have to explicitly do).

Comment: Ah OK! I'll go down the `new WP_Query( $args )` route in my PHP handler then - I suppose it's an opportunity to do something a little more clever than the default search (i.e. ordering results or date range querying etc)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of [Dave's WordPress Live Search](http://wordpress.org/plugins/daves-wordpress-live-search/), so I might be able to help you out a little bit here.

You definitely should familiarize yourself with the preferred way to do [AJAX in plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). This way, your code is flexible enough to work with all the different ways you or someone using your code might want to configure WordPress in the future.

Instead of just using `json_encode()` to send your response, consider using the new [wp_send_json_success](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) and [wp_send_json_error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error) functions to include a little extra status information that might come in handy when you're debugging things.

And, lastly, remember my search plugin is MIT licensed, so feel free to dig around in the code and see how I've done things. It's probably a lot more complicated that what you're looking to do, but you might pick up a few pointers from it.

Good luck!

Comment: `wp_send_json_success` and `wp_send_json_error` look interesting - thanks for highlighting them i'll definitely use them in my solution.

Comment: Also, just checking out your plugin now... looks awesome and will be V helpful!